# How to get C#.Net Assembly by name?

Tags: c#, assemblies

Is there something like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblyByName("TheAssemblyName")
```

so instead of looping through `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, we could just get the specific assembly directly.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [Assembly.Load(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.7.1)?

Comment: For those who are wondering, this throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` if the assembly could not be loaded.

Comment: Consider also `public static System.Reflection.Assembly LoadFrom (string assemblyFile);`

Answer (score 98):

I resolved with LINQ

```
Assembly GetAssemblyByName(string name)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().
           SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == name);
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the assembly in question is loaded. May not help when registering types in a DAL from a Web API

Answer (score 21):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you just want to get the assembly, then you should call `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load()` (as already pointed out). That's because .NET automatically checks if the assembly has already been loaded into the current AppDomain and doesn't load it again if it has been.

If you're just trying to *check* whether the assembly has been loaded or not (for some diagnostics reason, perhaps) then you do have to loop over all the loaded assemblies.

Another reason you might want to loop is if you know only some of the assembly information (eg. you're not sure of the version). That is, you know enough to "recognise it when you see it", but not enough to load it. That is a fairly obscure and unlikely scenario, though.

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.Load() is just as perfect as what I need.

Answer (score 18):

If this is an assembly you have referenced, I like to write a class like the following:

```cs
namespace MyLibrary {
   public static class MyLibraryAssembly {
      public static readonly Assembly Value = typeof(MyLibraryAssembly).Assembly;
   }
}
```

and then whenever you need a reference to that assembly:

```
var assembly = MyLibraryAssembly.Value;
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution that I've been always looking for! I can use it like this: `options.RegisterFromAssembly(Application.AssemblyReference.Value)`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it does not rely on some provided name.

Comment: Obviously, if it is a third-party assembly that you need a reference to, you cannot add a helper class like that, but you can simply pick any type that you know to be part of the assembly, e.g. `SomeThirdPartyLibraryClass`, and get the assembly reference as `typeof(SomeThirdPartyLibraryClass).Assembly`. A very nice tip!

Answer (score 9):

For those who just need to access the assembly's metadata (version, etc.) check out Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(name), which is able to load only the metadata, possibly saving on memory and IO.

Comment: @erik-reppen: According to MS docs it is available in previous versions. I'm using it in a 3.5 app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This would have been perfect for my use case, but alas it's not supported in .NET Core (as of 3.1)

Answer (score 5):

You can write an extension method that does what you need.

**This method will only enumerate loaded assemblies**, if you possibly need to load it, use `Assembly.Load` from the accepted answer.

```
public static class AppDomainExtensions
{
    public static Assembly GetAssemblyByName(this AppDomain domain, string assemblyName)
    {
        return domain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == assemblyName);
    }
}
```

Then you call this method on an AppDomain like this:

```
Assembly a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblyByName("SomeAssembly")
```

If *SomeAssembly* is loaded into the current AppDomain the method will return it, otherwise it will return `null`.

Comment: I didnot find GetAssemblyByName()

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the System.Reflection.Assembly class, in particular the Load method: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx)