# List of Assemblies in a different project within Solution VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, assemblies

My Solution(VS2010) has many projects.

At run time, How do I get list of all the assemblies in a given project?

I can get list of all assemblies within the calling code project by following line of code.

```
Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

How do I get list of assemblies in a project different than calling code project?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Check out the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies)

Comment: Paul - If I have a project called WebApplication1 then how do I get hold of WebApplication1 assembly? How do I do this var webassembly = GetAssembly("WebApplication1"); ? Thanks

Comment: Find a class you know is in that assembly, say it's called `MyClass`. Then you can do `typeof(MyClass).Assembly`. If you just have the string name, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913057/how-to-get-c-net-assembly-by-name).

Comment: Both of those answers you could have easily found by searching, by the way. Please do more research before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution may contain projects that are not referenced by the project you currently are executing. I don't know if there is a solid way to retrieve those.

However if your calling assembly does contain a reference to the other projects, you can walk through the [myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies) array. Note that this will also include referenced framework assemblies.